# Interactive axis rescaling matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I run Python from my terminal on Fedora at work and I run Python from my terminal on Debian (Plasma KDE) at home. On Fedora, I can rescale the plot axis after matplotlib has plotted the data but I can't rescale on Debian. I've tried several different backends and setting "matplotlib.interactive(1)" but obviously none of these have worked. Does anyone have an idea as to what the settings I need to rescale plots interactively are?

Many thanks,
Niall

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a Jupyter notebook with `%matplotlib notebook` (IPython magic command for interactive plots)?

I am not familiar with Debian, but apparently it's possible to use Jupyter with it:
[Tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-jupyter-notebook-with-python-3-on-debian-9)